# Redirect visitors only from Yelp.com

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, yelp

I would like visitor from my yelp listing to land on a different page of my website.

For example: On yelp.com my website URL is domain.com. But when the visitor clicks on that URL, they should be redirected to domain.com/newpage

I am trying to do this only for the visitors who come to my website through yelp. How is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just change the website url in your yelp listing?

Comment: I want to keep it the same. There should be some way to tackle this issue?

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but based on documentation it can't really be trusted. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st way is change the url as suggested in comment.

2nd is :

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($url,'yelp') !== false) {
    header("Location : YOUR_PAGE_URL");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the server variable

`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERRER"]`

in the landing page of your website.

If the host is yelp.com, then redirect to your desired page.

Be sure to sanitize the value before using it.  A malicious user could take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a variable to the url, so it goes to the normal landing page, or /newpage depending on that variable.

```
domain.com?from=Yelp
```

Then on your landing page:

```
<?php

if($_GET["from"] == "Yelp"){
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/newpage/');
}

?>
```

Comment: OP dont want to change the url.

Comment: And if you _were_ going to change the URL, why wouldn't you just change it to the page you wanted to go to in the first place?